# topic in rabbitmq and activemq

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic

all,

Background: now client produces many messages of different labels.Consumers may subscribe some labels of them(different consumer need different labels's msgs).
  Now method: I used direct exchange in rabbitmq, consumer declared queue for itself, exchange distribute msgs to these queues.
  Problem: there exsit many redundant msgs in queues which effects the performance.

A topic type in activemq supports user a method to distribute a msg to many subscribers, which need not creates large number queues for subscribers.
Does exsit a method in rabbitmq, or some suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: are the messages redundant or the queues?

Comment: the queues. i just want a msg(routing_key label1) broadcast/Multicast to consumer(interested at label1), which subsribe it. But now, the msg sends to different queues(need lagrely memory).

Comment: I understand that English may not be your first language but I am struggling to understand you.  Are you creating queues and then not reading from them? Or reading from them and then stopping reading from them.  If so you need to make them autodelete queues, when you are done with them disconnect from them, once disconnected they will disappear.

Comment: Thxs. i mean: in activemq, activemq can distribute a msg to many subsribers with multicast. In rabbitmq, exchange will distribute msg to each queue, and then consumer read it from queue. The msg exsit too many copys in memory if i have 100+ consumers. Thank you for help me.

Comment: sorry I cant help I only know about rabbit mq.  I didnt understand that was what you meant.

Comment: There are three kinds of msgs. consumer1 maybe need 1,2,3, consumer2 need 2,3 , consumer3 need 1, consumer4... i need to declare too many queues for all the consumers, and each queue had too many msgs which are same.